# Is there a TYPO3 DAM API guide?

Tags: typo3, dam

I need to write an import tool that takes a large number of existing images and create DAM records for them in a TYPO3 system.

The only DAM related manuals that I can find are frontend related, with nothing at all for the API. I have tried to look through the code itself, but there'S far too much in there to be able to find what I'm looking for.

So basically I'm looking for a good API manual/guide (if there is one) or an example of how what I need to do might be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there's no such API, last time when I had to perform similar task it was done with custom extension. All you need is to insert record to tx_dam table and eventually connect it with some category/categories with mm table.

On the other hand DAM has own `indexing` module, which allows you to create DAM records for files uploaded via other way than DAM module. Maybe it's not super comfortable and requires attention, but you can do what you need without additional programming.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I go about using this indexing module? Or at lease finding out more about it! Documentation on TYPO3 is few and far between, and pretty poor when you do find it!

Comment: Yeap, agree with you. All you can/need is to perform some tests on small amounts of files. There is a click-click wizard for indexing and it's quite easy... if you'll finally perform the task few times.

Comment: Thanks again. Answer accepted as you're the only who did and you speak sense!